# PHP Form validation not working properly

Tags: php, registration

I have a registration script on my page, and it's handled like this:

```
<?php
include "inc/config.php";
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $conditions = $_POST['conditions'];
        if($firstname==""||$lastname==""||$email==""||$pass==""||$conditions==""){
        echo "
        <p>Tiedoissa oli puutteita :(</p>
            <ul>";
            if($firstname == ""){
                echo "<li>Etunimi puuttuu.</li>";
            }
            if($lastname == ""){
                echo "<li>Sukunimi puuttuu. </li>";
            }
            if($email == ""){
                echo "<li>Sähköposti puuttuu. </li>";
            }
            if($pass == ""){
                echo "<li>Salasana puuttuu. </li>";
            }
            if($conditions == ""){
                echo "<li>Luitko ehdot? </li>";
            }
        echo "</ul>";
        return false;
        }
        $rq = "INSERT INTO Users (Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password) VALUES ($firstname,$lastname,$email,$pass)";
        if(!mysqli_query($dblink,$rq)){
            echo "Rekisteröityminen epäonnistui tuntemattomasta syystä! :(";
        }
        else{
            echo "Rekisteröinti onnistui!<br>
            Käyttäjätunnuksesi on <strong>$email</strong> ja salasanasi on <strong>$pass</strong>.<br>
            Voit nyt kirjautua sisään. 
            ";
        }


?>
```

I'm having troubles finding the right method of comparing the form value, as I've tried `==`,`===` and `NULL` on comparison. 
But I'm always getting all of the error messages, or none of them. What I'm doing wrong?

Here's the html of the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal span6" method="post" id="registrationform">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Etunimi</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Sukunimi</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="lastname">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Sähköposti</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Salasana</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" name="pass">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter"> Tilaan uutiskirjeen
              </label>
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="conditions"> Hyväksyn ehdot
              </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="registerbtn">Rekisteröidy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: use empty function http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php for comparing

Comment: Can you add print_r($_POST) at the top of the script, reload in the browser, and update your post with what it shows? And when you say you get "all of the error messages" can you specific which exactly? Because it appears unlikely you could see echo of your echo statements, and which ones are important

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection.  You either need to escape your input, or, since you are already using mysqli, why not use prepared statements?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You should have a look at [SQL Injection prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [PHP PDO](http://de2.php.net/pdo) for prepared statements, before using this script on a publicly accessible web server.

Comment: @MikeBrant I will take care of it pretty soon.

Comment: @MikeBrant is this enough to take care of any possible sql injection? `$firstname = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($firstname)));`

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen You should actually just use the provided `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function.

Comment: @MikeBrant and it's enough?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Yes it is sufficient to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is not in a **function** hence  **return false;** is not working as you expect, and code continues to execute below. Your comparisons may already be fine. Change that **return false;** to **die();**

Ok so here is probably where the problem lies

```
if($firstname=="" || $lastname=="" || $email=="" || $pass=="" || $conditions==""){
```

You are checking for that and that check is working even when you dont submit the form and it appears like everything has an error. So you need to make that comparison only when the form is submitted and not while normal load. So wrap your php code around some **isset** like

```
if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]))
{
 // all your php code
}
```

Other than that, your code is working fine. It compares like you expect it to.

Comment: Did it, but it still isn't working as it should. I have every field filled with text, and checkbox checked, but it still says that all fields aren't filled.

Comment: There, added. Anything strange in?

Comment: The registration page is called with jQuery AJAX, and it has nothing else than the script. So it's running only on when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Hi  you can use php fonction for example use  if(!isset($firstname)) or if(empty($firstname)) if you want to now if $firstname is Null